# Copy a .csv file to a .txt file

Tags: vba, excel

I am running below code but unable to save opened notepad file in same format, code is below

```
Dim mytxtfile
Dim flname, flname2 As String
flname = Dir(ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "myfile.csv")
flname2 = ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "myfile_1.txt"
mytxtfile = Shell("C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & flname, 1)
AppActivate mytxtfile
SendKeys "%(FAX)", True
Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 2)
SendKeys "%S", True '
```

"Save as" dialog box opens here, but now I want to give the file name which is in `flname2` i.e (myfile_1.txt) and then save and close notepad.

Comment: How can you open xL with notepad?

Comment: All you want to do is rename the file?

Comment: by using    Shell("C:\WINDOWS\notepad.exe " & ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & flname, 1)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file using the File System Object:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objFSO.CopyFile ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "myfile.csv", ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "myfile_1.txt"
```

Comment: In that case, please up vote it and accept as the answer (the help should have info on how to do both)